# Magento Ajax Cart

Tags: ajax, magento, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

Can anyone help me, I need to make a sidebar cart in Magento that need to remain in fixed position, I mean when I scroll the page to bottom for example the sidebar cart to move bottom too. Is there any extension or anyone can guide me. thank you

Comment: Something along the lines of this?  http://demo2.magento.stage.swarminglabs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to fix your cart's position as "fixed".
If your cart id is 'cart', then,

```
#cart
{
 position: fixed;
}
```